# Is it possible to run my test app in Actions in Google Assistant Offline?

Tags: actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk

I know it seems impossible, but maybe who knows? Anyway, tried sharing my test app, run it thru Google assistant and it works perfectly fine. But i was wondering if maybe i can invoke my test app even when i'm offline/no internet connection.

Any help/tips are appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

No.

Actions on Google is a more web-like model of deployment, where the Assistant on your device and in Google's cloud acts like a web browser to send requests to and get requests from a server on the Internet. Very little actually runs on the device itself.

Comment: ahh is that so. Got it, Thanks!